# Repetition of a method

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, infinite-loop, predicate

How would I go about it if i want to repeat the method if neither yes or no is typed? I tried:

> while (!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no")) {

But it just kept typing "please answer either yes or no" without giving the option of writing again.

Thx

```js
import acm.program.*;

public class YesOrNoQuestion extends ConsoleProgram {
 public void run() {
  println("This program asks you whether you want instructions");
  String answer = readLine("Type your answer here: ");
  YesOrNo(answer);
 }

 private void YesOrNo(String answer) {
  if (answer.equals("yes")) {
   println("Alright here you go");
  } if (answer.equals("no")) {
   println("Alright fine");
  } else println("Please type either yes, or no: ");
  
 }
}
```

Comment: you should call `run` again in the `else` part of `YesOrNo`, or use recursion by the last two statement´s of the `run` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are missing the `else if` !!
- Also, convert user entry to lowercase with [`String::toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) to get `NO`, `nO`,  `No` and `no`.
- To print in console use [`System.out.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

```
private void YesOrNo(String answer) {
    if (answer.toLowerCase.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Alright here you go");
    } else if (answer.toLowerCase.equals("no")) {
    //↑ here!!!
        System.out.println("Alright fine");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please type either yes, or no: ");
        run();
    }

}
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but this shouldn´t make a difference if i enter anything different from `yes` or `no`?

Comment: i guess you did edit the `run()` into the else part as i was writing the comment :).

Comment: oh... you meant if answer isn't yes or no!!!! AGREE, i've realized of that later... ;) thanks for the catch anyway